# Data contract for Web API Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm in the process of creating a Web API service, and I'm wondering how to create some of my data contracts. The three contracts can be found below:

```
public class AccessRequest
{
    [Key]
    public int AccessRequestID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AccessRequestAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class AccessRequestAnswer
{
    [Key]
    public int AccessRequestAnswerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AccessRequestID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AccessRequestQuestionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

public class AccessRequestQuestion
{
    [Key]
    public int AccessRequestQuestionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
}
```

When dealing with the `AccessRequestAnswer` class, should I include the int `AccessRequestQuestionID` or should I include an actual instance of `AccessRequestQuestion`?

I'm using Entity Framework. Would EF be smart enough to know that It will need to also return the question or would I have to manually add that in my repository?

If you need more clarification, just let me know!

Comment: rename your long Primary Key IDs as "Id" in your classes. I'd certainly add the Foreign Keys as Navigation Property Objects.

Comment: @Dynamic why should I rename them? Isn't it good practice to describe the primary key?

Comment: No, Primary Key is always ID, it's a waste to describe it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the navigation property to your AccessRequestAnswer class.

```
public virtual AccessRequestQuestion AccessRequestQuestion {get;set;}
```

Check the MSDN [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx)